# Problem in getting the datepicker value when web-scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am web-scraping the date value inputted in the datepicker below. I have located the HTM of the datepicker. However, It shows no date value and my Python code returns nothing. Am I using a wrong method?

Webpage link: https://rate.amcm.gov.mo/en/financial-information/middle-rates

Target HTML: `<input type="text" class="date-picker" id="display-picker">`

[image: Target date]

My Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

url = 'https://rate.amcm.gov.mo/en/financial-information/middle-rates'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
input_date = driver.find_element_by_id('display-picker')
print(input_date.text)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Yes, the date value (as rates) is gathered through a post request. Then, some js script fill the HTML input. Look at F12->Network->XHR, and build a post request with the 'requests' package.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the data through XHR successfully. But the date I got is like "1629388800". Do you know how to transform it into a normal format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date is in this format - `1629388800` then you can convert it to readable format using `datetime` module.

```
from datetime import datetime
x = 1629388800
d = datetime.strftime(datetime.fromtimestamp(x), '%d/%m/%Y')
print(d)
```

```
19/08/2021
```

Comment: Thank ce.teuf and Ram, problem solved! For those who need more information, you can refer to [here](https://danielms.site/blog/web-scraping-javascript-with-python-xhr/) for more about how to get an XHR response.